# A unrecognized part in date time string

Tags: java, datetime-format

I'm using hotelbeds API (developer.hotelbeds.com) and I'm getting a date string in a JSON response as follows.

```
"cancellationPolicies": [
   {
     "amount": "407.56",
     "from": "2016-09-19T23:59:00-04:00"
   }
]
```

Does anyone know what is that "-04:00" means? I already checked the API docs and cannot find anything. 
I want to parse this date string in to a Date Object in Java, something like this,

```
Date fromDate = new SimpleDateFormat("pattern").parse("dateTimeString");
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The `-04:00` is the timezone and you can't discard it unless you assume it is always this value.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, [right here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

Comment: Refer the API  : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know what is that "-04:00" means?

It is simply the timezone offset, here it means GMT minus 4 hours.